# Comparing values within a column using sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table with three columns Member, id and DOB. I want to assign a id to each unique member. If there is more than one id tagged for a member then I have to assign id with more recurrence. If a tie occurs then I have to assign id with most recent DOB.

```
4000  8569 11/11/1993
4111  9653 12/11/1993
4000  8569 12/12/1993
5000  5632 01/01/1993
4000  6932 31/12/1993
4111  6987 06/11/1993
5001  4356 01/01/1993
```

In the above, member's 5000 and 5001 is tagged to single id.. So I should get the same id for that member.. Whereas for member 4000 I am having 3 id's- 2 same ids (8569) and one different id (6987). Here I should have 8569 tagged to this 4000 member. For 4111 member, I am having two different ids (9653 and 6987). So I will see recent DOB for that member. So for 4111 member I will have 9653 tagged to it.

The output should be like this:

```
4000 8569
4111 9653
5000 5632
5001 4356
```

I have tried many. But I couldn't get the exact answer. Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [window functions in t-sql](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx):

```
create table #t (
    Member int,
    id int,
    DOB date
);

insert into #t
values  (4000, 8569, '1993-11-11'),
        (4111, 9653, '1993-11-12'),
        (4000, 8569, '1993-12-12'),
        (5000, 5632, '1993-01-01'),
        (4000, 6932, '1993-12-31'),
        (4111, 6987, '1993-11-06'),
        (5001, 4356, '1993-01-01');

with cte as
(
    select *, count(id) over (partition by member, id) cnt from #t
),
cte2 as
(
    select *, row_number() over (partition by member order by cnt desc, dob desc) rn from cte
)
select member, id from cte2 where rn = 1;

drop table #t;
```